Rigify Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'
It's my first time using blender for rigging so I am a bit lost.
I have placed all the bones in the metarig in their correct place in edit mode. When I try to generate the rig, I get this error message:
CONFLICT: bone {bone.name} owned by rig {rig.base_bone} has different parent rig from ORG-thigh.R
Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'

As you can see, the problematic bones are not displayed correctly in the error message, so I am a bit in the dark. I have checked the parents and bone type of both my legs, but everything seems normal.
I have tested generating a fresh rig in a new scene, and everything works normally.
EDIT: Turns out the missing names in the bracket is just a bug in the source code. When fixed, it displays the names correctly. The error message is now :
CONFLICT: bone ORG-heel.02.R owned by rig ORG-thigh.R has different parent rig from ORG-thigh.R
Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'

There is enough ressource online to guide from here.

My problem was the same as everyone else online: I had accidentally changed the rigify type of one of my bones (foot.R in my case).
For the bug, line 501 of base_generate.py is
raise MetarigError("CONFLICT: bone {bone.name} owned by rig {rig.base_bone} "
It should be raise MetarigError(f"CONFLICT: bone {bone.name} owned by rig {rig.base_bone} " instead. I'll try to make a bug report later.
